# React parent method passed in child component has stale state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my App.js, I have the following:

```
const(sound,SetSound) = useState('beep');
function playSound() {
    console.log(sound); // displays beep if called from childComponent and 'honk' if called from App.js
}
return (
<Childcomponent
    sound={sound}
    setSound={setSound}
    playSound={playSound}
/>
...
```

In my ChildComponent I do the following:

```
props.setSound('honk');
//Later by button click:
props.playSound();
```

Instead of honking it beeps.  What am I missing?

In app.js I catch keypress 'a' to call playSound().  When I do that it honks after the childComponent updated it.  Somehow the props.playSound() is stale though.  If I display {sound} in childComponent, it shows the updated 'honk'.

I tried 'binding' with
playSound={() => playSound()}
But it still beeps instead of honking.

How do I honk from ChildComponent?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten your code.

Comment: Maybe don't use `useState`... reconfigure your code to call `playSound('honk')`?

Answer (score 0):

What does your `playSound()` function look like?
Seems like `playSound()` is still using the old state of `sound`.

In App.js, I would pass the value to the `playSound` function so that it uses the correct, updated value of `sound`:

```
function playSound(sound) {
  // Plays the sound with the argument passed in.
}
```

Comment: There are several state variables that are used in my playSound unfortunately.  I simplified the code to show the problem.  I could use your approach but it would be tedious and unelegant.  But if all else fails...

Comment: how about useEffect hook and adding `sound` as a dependency. Inside useEffect call `playSound()`. It will only fire when the value of `sound`  is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `setSound` with value `'honk'`, it won't be available to `playSound` in the same tick. You've to wait for next render cycle and then call `props.playSound()`

Or you could do something like this

```
// This will ensure that playSound is called after setting the state
props.setSound('honk', () => props.playSound());
```

Comment: I don't call it immediately. The code is simplified.  I tried pressing 'a' before pressing the button that calls props.playsound. 'a' honks. The button beeps.

Comment: The code you shared is incomplete. We can only guess. It's hard to say where the problem is without looking at the playSound function

Comment: Yes.  I was hoping it was a simple pattern i had overlooked.  But if it *should* work as I stated it, then I have some unintended side effects somewhere.  You think that's probably it then?

Comment: Without sharing the actual code we can't help you. Here is a simple sandbox for you and it works fine, check the console. https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-firefly-eg39qm?file=/src/App.js